# Get presence state for other windows accounts?

Tags: powershell, vbscript, exchange-server, jscript

My boss was asking me to build a tool for all users to check the presence state for other coworkers (Online, Offline, Busy, etc...). Normally we use MS Teams or Outlook for that purpose but not everyone has access to these in my company.

So I thought about some VBScript, JScript or PowerShell-Script for that simple purpose. So far I had no luck finding a solution except for MS Graph, which apparently requires administrative privileges (and appears over the top either way):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript

Any useful ideas?

Comment: Does that mean that you want to write a script that defines the state itself (something like checking the input devices?) and share that which the others (or just the boss)???

Comment: If you use MS Outlook or MS Teams you may look for any other user by his E-Mail and see his presence state at this moment (e.g. a green circle = online). Thats what the Script should do for people without these programs: Ask the user to type in someones mail-address@company.com, then read the presence state of that person from the server and display it to the user.

Comment: IN PS: `query user /server:$SERVER` ?

Comment: Without admin privileges the query user command returns no result. Also we have more than 500 pcs and some people switch between 2 or more workstations.